# How to declare methods nested class outside that receive class

Tags: c++

I tried in my own code to create definition of something, but the compiler couldn't recognize it, so just simply the code, I made a more short-abstract code that will represent what I'm trying to do:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    class B
    {
        T x;
    public:
        B() : x(0) {}
        ~B(){}

        void printAB() const;
        B& increase();
    };
};
```

Now, I want to make a definiton of `printAB` and `increase` outside the class, so `printAB` doesn't make any problem because it returns void, but when I'm trying to make definiton of `PrintAB` the compiler doesn't recognize it and make red underline under it:

This one works good:

```
template <class T>
void A<T>::B::printAB() const
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

And this one it doesn't recognize:

```
template<class T>
A::B & A<T>::B::increase()
{
    x++;
    return *this;
}
```

I also tried to make this declaration:

```
template<class T>
A<T>::B & A<T>::B::increase() {
...
}
```

I must say that it doesn't work with A as you guys suggested, so please any other solution that may help?

Comment: `template<class T> A<T>::B & A<T>::B::increase()`

Comment: @SergeyA, I tried this one, and it doesn't seem to show underline error, but when I'm trying to compile, it says: "synax error" on that line.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Just like you need `A<T>` in `A<T>::B::increase()` you also need it in `A::B`.  `A::B` should be `A<T>::B`

Comment: @NathanOliver as I already said, it doesn't work with `A<T>::B` also

Comment: Ah, yep, forgot you need `typename` first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords.  `A<T>::B & A<T>::B::increase()` -> `typename A<T>::B & A<T>::B::increase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  should to tell compiler what we meant by `A<T>::B`

```
template<class T> 
typename A<T>::B & A<T>::B::increase() 
{
    x++;
    return *this;
}
```